# Are emails I delete from the Updates category also deleted from other folders like Inbox?

Tags: gmail

If I delete emails from the Updates category in Gmail, will they also get deleted from other folders like my Inbox?

If so, how can I delete emails from Updates without also  losing them completely?

Answer (score 3):

If you ***delete*** emails anywhere in Gmail, they are moved to the Trash folder which means they will no longer show up in any other folders including your Inbox.

Deleted emails can be restored/undeleted from Trash for 30 days after which point they will be permanently deleted by Gmail and lost forever.

If you only want to remove the emails from Updates, and keep them in other folders like your Inbox, **do not delete** them but instead **remove the label `Updates`** from the emails.